# How to use meteor to append more html to a div?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In jquery it's easy, `$('#xiv').append('my html')` but it looks messy due to mixing HTML and JavaScript.

How can I do this the meteor way ?

Comment: you should look at the examples. what do you want to append and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use jQuery in Meteor.

**The meteor way is not to alter your divs manually with snippets of HTML.**

Instead, define a Meteor template that explains how to reproduce the html for a page based on the underlying data.  Then subscribe your app to the data and its updates.

The [classic leaderboard Meteor example](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) contains this template:

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  <div class="leaderboard">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>

  {{#if selected_name}}
  <div class="details">
    <div class="name">{{selected_name}}</div>
    <input type="button" class="inc" value="Give 5 points" />
  </div>
  {{else}}
  <div class="none">Click a player to select</div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Look at the first `div`, with class leaderboard.

The `{{#each players}}` doesn't look like HTML, does it?

The '{{#each array}}`is a template directive that causes the HTML up to the closing`{{/each}}`to be executed in a loop over the array, in this case the`players` array.

The `{{>player}}` calls the template for an individual player.

Here is the player template that is being called.  The individual player template is called over and over in the each loop with the data for each particular player.

```
<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template> template:
```

There is a javascript side to this as well, but it is well covered in the leaderboard example and in the primary meteor docs.